# How to use plist NSString items as UIImageView object names

Tags: iphone, ios, reflection, nsstring, uiimageview

I am trying an array item as a the object name.

I have 5 `UIImageView`s set up:

```
@interface miniTestViewController : UIViewController {

    NSArray *array;

    IBOutlet UIImageView *sun;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *moon;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *rain;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *snow;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *hail;
}

-(IBAction)fadeChosenImage:(id)sender;
```

My plist contains an array of image names: sun, moon, rain, snow, hail

In the .m VDL stub, this plist is read into an `NSArray *array`.

A `UIButton` tag selects the object at index:

```
-(IBAction)fadeChosenImage:(id)sender{

    NSString *image = [[NSString alloc] init];  
    image= nil;

    switch ([sender tag]) { 
        case 0: 
            image = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
            break; 
        case 1: 
            image = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            image = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
            break; 
        case 3: 
            image = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
            break; 
        case 4: 
            image = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]]; 
            break; 
        default: 
            break;
    }
```

I need to use the `NSString` as the `UIImageView` object name, like this:

```
[[array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] setAlpha:0];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:6.0];
[[array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]] setAlpha:1];
```

but so far `objectAtIndex` returns a `NSString` which does not respond to the `setAlpha` message.

Is it possible to convert/wrap/cast/use the `NSString` to the object name of the `UIImageVIew`

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much easier to save your image view objects into the array directly, rather than trying to retrieve them using a string.

If you want to find objects using a string as a key, store them in a dictionary.

Hoever, in your case, you have a numeric index. Just save the UIImageView objects directly into your array. That does not duplicate the objects - it just saves references to them in your array.

Answer (score 0):

Try [`object_getInstanceVariable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/object_getInstanceVariable):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

...

UIImageView *imageView = nil;
NSString *name = [array objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];
object_getInstanceVariable(self, [name UTF8String], (void**)&imageView);
```

Comment: Gack. Really? Using the low-level Objective C runtime as a solution for a newbie?!? The docs say that that method returns "A pointer to the Ivar data structure that defines the type and name of the instance variable specified by name". Is that the same thing as a high level pointer to an object, assuming that the instance variable contains an object? The docs say that an iVar is "An opaque type that represents an instance variable."